# Modelling heteroscedastic longitudinal data

Tags: r, lm, linear

I am looking at % protein in the same 20 individuals over several time points.
I have some missing data points and my data is heteroscedastic (as confirmed by Bartlett's test).
I believe that a linear mixed model is right for me (?), but I'm not quite sure how to proceed.
I have found the following code that adjusts the p values for unequal variance:

```
library(sandwich)
x<-lm(Value~Group)
summary(x)
vcovHC(x,type="HC")
sandwich_se<-diag(vcovHC(x,type="HC"))^0.5
sandwich_se
coef(x)-1.96*sandwich_se
coef(x)+1.96*sandwich_se
z_stat<-coef(x)/sandwich_se
p_values<-pchisq(z_stat^2,1,lower.tail=FALSE)
p_values
```

I think that this is close to what I need but I'm not sure this model applies to repeated measures.
Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question to you is first, what exactly are you trying to do? What is the research question/purpose of analysis? Your post is missing context.

When working with longitudinal data, I generally prefer working with Generalized Estimating Equations since they provide robust standard errors and are generally computationally faster. In addition, I find it easier to present these models to non-statisticians.

With that said, I recommend you NOT use the `lm` function for your analyses. Try the packages `geepack` for GEEs or `lme4` for Generalized Linear Mixed Models. Both can be used for modeling correlated data, such as longitudinal/repeated measures. `geepack` has a useful paper:

https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v015i02

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to know if there is a change in % protein over time. The 20 individuals are all the same species and were used as replicates, rather than a second variable, if that makes sense. I will try your suggestions.